# Will ResultSet leak if not explicitly closed?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I'm using jdbc connection pooling with jetty, had this setup on a server instance with no problems for over a year. I've switched to a new ubuntu server, and keep running out of memory. I'm profiling memory usage and see the following top class instances:

```
java.util.Hashtable$Entry (33%)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$BooleanConnectionProperty (13%)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$StringConnectionProperty (3%)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$IntegerConnectionProperty (3%)
```

I'm not explicitly closing my ResultSet instances, I'm doing something like:

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
try {
    conn = ...;
    stmt = ...;
    ResultSet rs = ...;
    rs.useIt();
}
finally {
    if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    if (conn != null) { conn.close(); }
}
```

The docs say that the Statement will close associated ResultSet instances when it gets closed - is it possible that the jdbc implementation on this ubuntu machine is not actually doing that? I haven't made any changes in my code (a packaged .war file), I just dropped it into a jetty instance on this ubuntu machine as-is.

The profiling shows those com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl instances continuing to grow, so guessing maybe this is what's happening.

I just wanted to check before I go off and modify all my code to explicitly close the ResultSet instances. Looking at MySql Workbench, I don't see anything out of the ordinary in the Client Connections view - my app connections come in and appear to get cleaned up ok.

Thanks

-------------------- Update --------------------

I've changed all my instances of ResultSet to close them immediately as well as in the finally {} block, just like my Connection and PreparedStatement instances. This doesn't seem to be helping though, memory keeps growing.

Poking around some more, I noticed the class:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
```

and the number of instances never decrease. After about 10 minutes of up time, I'm seeing almost 5k instances (yikes?).

This post looks very similar to what I'm running into:

[Memory leak in JDBC4Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338445/memory-leak-in-jdbc4connection)

The OP says in the end:

> the ORM relied on closing connection to free resources in finalizer (sometimes over closing the result sets and statements), but the pool kept the connections open for several hours, and in case of any peak, this caused OOM.

I don't understand what that means, or how one would go about fixing that. I'm pretty sure I'm closing my resources everywhere now (otherwise when I was running the same webapp on my other windows server, I may have seen a leak there, too?).

-------------------- Update --------------------

Still seeing the same behavior, this is how I'm opening a db connection in each request I handle (error checking omitted):

```
 public class DsHelper {
    private static DsHelper sInstance;
    private DataSource mDs;

    public DsHelper() {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        mDs = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myds");
    }

    public static DsHelper get() { 
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new DsHelper();
        }

        return mInstance;
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return mDs;
    }
}
```

using it:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                     HttpServletResponse response) 
{
    Connection conn = null; 
    try {
        conn = DsHelper.get().getDataSource();
        ...
    }
    finally {
        if (conn != null) { conn.close(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good practice to close the `ResultSet` too, but I think closing the `Statement` will also invalidate (and I suspect close) the `ResultSet`. I don't believe it is guaranteed though, which is why you should [clean up after yourself](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html).

Comment: I think they're all closed, still seeing the mem growth - updated my q with some new info though, thanks!

Comment: How are you opening connections? Do you use DriverManager, or some kind of DataSource (which?)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel updated answer with the way I'm opening the connections.

Comment: @user3203425 Seriously, look at my blog post linked above. I wrote that due to Oracle issues with WebLogic but it worked there.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes agreed about closing everything explicitly, I've done this now but still seeing the same behavior. The strange thing again is that I was not seeing this on my old windows machine, it's only happening on my ubuntu machine.

Comment: @user3203425 I know Jetty has several configuration options for the pool. I'd start checking there.

Comment: My guess would be that you use a connection pool that is wrapping objects like connections, statements and maybe even result sets and not handling the `close()` on them correctly. You might want to see if you can reproduce the memory leak by creating physical connections from `DriverManager` instead. Also check if you are using a recent driver version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ResultSet leaks are notoriously common.  Closing them explicitly is a really good idea, and worth every bit of the trouble you will take to do it diligently. Go do it! Seriously.

Different VM implementations handle garbage collection differently. That may be why you're seeing stuff pile up in your new environment.

On Oracle, ResultSet objects are reflections of scarce server resources (cursors) and if you don't close them explicitly, eventually your server runs out and other connections' work starts to fail.

Go clean 'em up!

Comment: Ok I think they're all explicitly closed now, but still seeing the same behavior. Updated my original post with some updated info, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on Statement javadoc, ResultSet need not be closed explicitly.

[From javadocs page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html),

> Note:When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object,
>   if one exists, is also closed.

But I would recommend closing the ResultSet as soon as the task with it is done. Oracle's Statement implementation, had issues with the open cursors even after closing the connection. So there is a possibility for exceptions like "Maximum open cursors exceeded".

You can avoid explicit closing of Statement as well with latest feature introduced in java 1.7.
Better & cleaner code would be (if you are using Java 1.7+)

```
public static void viewTable(Connection con) throws SQLException {

    String query = "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL from COFFEES";

    try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
            int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
            float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
            int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
            int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");

            System.out.println(coffeeName + ", " + supplierID + ", " + 
                               price + ", " + sales + ", " + total);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    }
}
```

Observe the difference in try block syntax and observe there is no explicit close method calls. It is taken care of, internally. Reference - [try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: It is up to the specific JDBC driver implementation to correctly close the resources. The fact that the API documents it does not necessarily mean that all implementations comply!

Comment: @MarkRotteveel But surely they do? Surely there's a certification step they have to pass?

Comment: @EJP No. See also DB2's batching implementation. Hint, it isn't like anyone else's.

Comment: @EJP There is - afaik - no real certification, except passing the TCK; and getting your hands on that as an open source project involves a lot of red tape and jumping through Oracle bureaucracy hoops... And as a commercial business forking over money to Oracle every year.